# error:"non_field_errors": [ "Unable to log in with provided credentials." ]

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

```
class ProfesRegister(serializers.ModelSerializer):
password =serializers.CharField( style={'input_type': 'password'} )
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username','password','email']

def create(self,validated_data):
    username = validated_data.get('username')
    password = validated_data.get('password')
    user = User (username=username,email=validated_data.get('email'))
    user.set_password('password')
    
    user.save()
    Token.objects.create(user=user)
    
    return user
    




INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'student',
'unit',
'universityAndProfes',

'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'rest_auth',
```

]

```
urlpatterns = [
path('api/',include(router.urls)),
path('api/auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
path('api/register/', ProfesRegisteration.as_view() ),
```

]

i use rest auth to login and i get an token error!
im sure when i register my user token is generated but i cant login and authenticate!!

here is the view for my registering

```
class ProfesRegisteration(generics.CreateAPIView):
serializer_class= ProfesRegister
authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in your code in the `create` method.

```
def create(self,validated_data):
    username = validated_data.get('username')
    password = validated_data.get('password')
    ... 
    user.set_password(password)
    ...
```

In your code, it was `set_password('password')` so it was getting all the passwords as 'password' instead of actual password